# Ubuntu 13.10 on MBA 6.2 performance is worse than on MBA 5.2

Tags: 13.10, 14.04, macbook-air

Running sysbench on the 6.2 compared to the 5.1 Macbook Air is a whole lot slower. Here is the command I'm running:

```
sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=20000 run
```

On the 6.2 it runs in around 48 seconds, and on the 5.1 it runs in 25 seconds!

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

You must enable the intel_pstate driver via grub to allow turbo boost to work:

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/prevent-your-laptop-from-overheating.html

I measured 48 seconds before and 25 seconds after enabling this. You can verify the frequency via:

```
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
cpufreq-info -c 0
```